# Create additional SEO-style link using PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, seo

I have a two page website -- a home page and an about page.  I am trying to add a third page, but I am having a hard time figuring out the correct code.

I have this PHP at the top of my index.php page...

```
$tmp=str_replace("index.php","",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$tmp=explode("/",$tmp);
$i=1;
$path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
foreach($tmp as $str){
    if($i==1){
        $q=$str;
        $path=str_replace('about/','',$path);
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

And this in my nav area...

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> <li<?php if(empty($q)){echo"
class=\"active\"";}?>><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
Home</a></li>

    </ul> <?php if(defined('emailReceiver')&&emailReceiver){?> <ul
class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li<?php if(!empty($q)&&$q=="about"){echo"
        class=\"active\"";}?>><a href="<?php echo$path;?>about/"><i
        class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i>  About This
        Site</a></li> </ul>
```

I think I need to create other instances of $i -- but I am not sure exactly what.

Comment: I don't understand your if statement. It's always `1` because you assign it to `1` before the loop.

Comment: there is really no such thing as an *SEO-style link* search engines don't care.

Comment: Are these hardcoded pages?? I am trying to figure out why you don't just do a .htaccess rewrite rule?